# How do I turn a string with random length in array of bytes C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, byte

I need to turn something like "0.014" in array of bytes, where first "0" = arr[0], "."= arr[1] and so on...
and also turn them to Little Endian.
My code works fine, but I have a problem with the length of the string and sometimes it gives out of bound exception
Here is my code:

```
public void convertErrToByte(string errString, byte[] errToByte3)
    {              
        string errString2 = "";
        byte[] errToByte = new byte[errString.Length];
        byte[] errToByte2 = new byte[errString.Length];       
        
        for (int i = 0; i < errString.Length; i++)
        {
            errToByte[i] = Convert.ToByte(errString[i]); 
        }
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < errToByte.Length - 1; i += 2) 
            {
                errToByte2[i] = errToByte[i + 1];
                errToByte2[i + 1] = errToByte[i];
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
        for (int i = 0; i < errToByte2.Length; i++)
        {
            errString2 += errToByte2[i].ToString("X"); 
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < errString2.Length; i++)
        {
            errToByte3[i] = Convert.ToByte(errString2[i]); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: You seem to have a lot more going on in code than your description has specified, Which makes this question a little unclear

Comment: yes, sorry for that it just my first post here... I will try to edit it

Comment: Sure you can, just press the edit button, the more precise you make the question the faster it will be answered

Comment: found it thank you, I removed the unnecessarily

Comment: Have a look at the example @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.unicode?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: It seems like a lot of code when `System.Text.Encoding.(encodingname).GetBytes(string)` is a thing

Comment: Didn't know I can do it that way. I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using ASCII Encoding:

```
    private void swapBytePair(ref byte[] bytes)
    {
        if (bytes.Length == 0)
            return;

        byte temp;
        int len = (bytes.Length % 2 == 0) ? bytes.Length : bytes.Length - 1;

        for (int i=0; i < len; i+=2)
        {
            temp = bytes[i];
            bytes[i] = bytes[i + 1];
            bytes[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFG");
    swapBytePair(ref bytes);
    //result: "BADCFEG"
```

I think you had issues with uneven string lengths, my method ignores the last byte, since there is nothing to swap with.

Comment: what I need to do is lets say I have string like "0.01", so the array will be arr[0]= 0x30, arr[1] = 0x2e, arr[2] = 0x30, arr[3] = 0x31; and from 30,2e,30,31 it has to become 2e,30,31,30 and it works the problem is sometime the string comes like "0.031" and in the cycle where I replace them I get exception because I reach out the array length

Comment: There is `Encoding.Unicode` (Little Endian) and `Encoding.BigEndianUnicode` (Big Endian)

Comment: I'm sorry about the dumb question but how do I use Encoding.Unicode. I looked on the internet but still cant get it..

Comment: I have edited my answer, maybe this is what you want. I think there is a general confusion what little or big endian means. Do you want to swap position 0 and 1, 2 and 3 ... or do you want to change how your byte is saved in the memory ? Do you really want to swap the first 4 bit with the last 4 ? Because this is what endian is all about.

Comment: you are right I had issues with uneven string lengths, and I want to swap 0 and 1, 2 and 3 and so on... thanks for the answer :) very helpful